# Converting vector tiles to shapefiles

Tags: convert, vector-tiles

I am relatively new to QGIS and I am not familiar with a lot of the ability and tools the program has.
I got a vector tile URL from a website about the Austrian soil rating.
[https://bodenkarte.at/data/bodenkarte-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://bodenkarte.at/data/bodenkarte-tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)
as well as the style:
https://bodenkarte.at/styles/ackerwert.json

I have not found a way to edit these layers like you can with normal shape layers.
That's why I am looking for a way to convert the vector tiles layer into a normal shape data so I can work with it. Is this possible at all?

Any tips?

Comment: vector tile are mean to be used as basemap and mostly not for anything else. You should try to find the source data (the webmap at https://bodenkarte.at/ seem to offer some download option, as I don't speak german I can't say of what exactly)

Comment: They offer a 1km by 1km raster which is not really usefull at all. So the Idea behind vector tiles is just to have a quick loading map, but not that you actually work with it or change it? Thanks for the clearification :)